# Auto Suggestion search box with php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with this code, it's about a search box that uses ajax to make auto suggestions for the user, I am testing the code but it seems to be not working, any suggestions?

The HTML code :-

```
<input class="autosuggest" name="autosuggest" type="text"></input>
```

and the JavaScript code:-

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){
        var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
        $.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
 });
```

Now the PHP page:-

```
    <?php
require_once "database/db.php";

if(isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false){
    echo"something";
    }
}

?>
```

Now this code is supposed to give me an alert box with the value "something", isn't it? It is just giving me an empty alert box and I don't know why!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at your request in debug tools (firebug or chrome development tolls). Does your server script return "something" ? Then, in your javascript code use console.log(data) and see what value does it have.

Comment: Indeed, I used console.log(search_term) and found that it's undefined. User $(...).val() to get your input value and don't forget to debug

Comment: thanks victor, i am trying now :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you're only searching from the database, and not modifying the database in any way, you should use `GET` instead :) also, some changes:

1. Use `$(this).val()` instead.
2. Specify `dataType` as JSON. As `$.get()` tries to guess intelligently the dataType, it might get it wrong sometimes... especially when you are echoing plain text. So try to use JSON instead - and it will pay back later, when you are returning search results (in arrays) from your DB when you actually get around to do it.
3. In your PHP, echo your result in JSON format using the PHP function `json_encode()`. See explanation above.

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){
        var search_term = $(this).val();
        $.get(
            'search.php',
            {
                search_term: search_term
            },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            'json'
        });
    });
});
```

If you are using `GET`, remember to update your PHP script, too:

```
<?php
    require_once("database/db.php");
    if(isset($_GET['search_term']) && !empty($_GET['search_term'])){
        echo json_encode("something");
    }
}
?>
```

---

Other notes for optimization:

**Throttling `keyup()`**. I usually avoid listening to the `keyup` event directly, because your users may type very quickly resulting in a deluge of data sent back and forth. Instead, try throttling it with [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), and it's rather easy to implement:

```
$('.autosuggest').keyup($.throttle(250 ,function(){  // Unobstructive throttling

    // Your code here

}));  // Remember to close the parenthesis for the $.throttle() method
```

**Use 'search' as input type**. For better usability, use `<input type="search" ... />` for your search field. Plus, for older or incompatible browsers that don't recognize the type, the field will simply revert back to `<input type="text" ... />`

**Serialize form data**. I rely on serialization to streamline the process, and keep the AJAX function clean from clutter (otherwise you'll have to enumerate all the fields you want to submit). This can be done easily by using `$('form').serialize()` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) instead of `{search_term: search_term}`.

Comment: I know :) but it's a matter of using the right method. If you are only querying the database, you should use `GET` instead of `POST` - here's [a guide to decide which to use](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with your search_term variable name being the same as the name of the array key, because strings can be used as keys too. Thus, js is converting the key to a string that contains the value of .autosuggest. Try changing the variable name to the_search_term. Example:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){
        var the_search_term = $(this).attr('value');
        $.post('search.php', {search_term:the_search_term}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: You cant write {search_term: search_term}, no problem here

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can't write it? Please explain if you will. Thanks Victor.

Comment: I wrote many times something like $.getJSON('url.php', {data:data},...); and it worked perfectly. So the variable names can be the same

Comment: I see. So js doesn't covert it. That's interesting behavior. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: `{search_term: search_term}` is actually a shorthand for `data:  {search_term: search_term}`, so I don't see anything wrong with it... right?

Comment: Terry, right. The brackets and what's inside is a generic object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple tools for auto suggestion:

- [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)
- [typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)